# Unknown function: pathogen#infect

Tags: vim, nerdtree, pathogen

I just installed MacVim (and did an override of Vim). And I am trying to get Pathogen to work. When I start Vim, I get the following error:

```
Error detected while processing /Users/nir/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim:
line    1:
E477: No ! allowed: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
line    2:
E488: Trailing characters: <html><head>
line    3:
Press ENTER or type command to continue

E488: Trailing characters: <title>302 Found</title>
line    4:
E488: Trailing characters: </head><body>
line    5:
E488: Trailing characters: <h1>Found</h1>
line    6:
E488: Trailing characters: <p>The document has moved <a href=
line    7:
E488: Trailing characters: <hr>
line    8:
E488: Trailing characters: <address>Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at tpo.pe Port 443</address>
line    9:
E488: Trailing characters: </body></html>
line    1:
E477: No ! allowed: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
line    2:
E488: Trailing characters: <html><head>
line    3:
E488: Trailing characters: <title>302 Found</title>
line    4:
E488: Trailing characters: </head><body>
line    5:
E488: Trailing characters: <h1>Found</h1>
line    6:
E488: Trailing characters: <p>The document has moved <a href=
line    7:
E488: Trailing characters: <hr>
line    8:
E488: Trailing characters: <address>Apache/2.2.22 (Debian) Server at tpo.pe Port 443</address>
line    9:
E488: Trailing characters: </body></html>
Error detected while processing /Users/nirchernia/.vimrc:
line    1:
E117: Unknown function: pathogen#infect
E15: Invalid expression: pathogen#infect()
```

My .vimrc looks like this

```
execute pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on
```

And my directory looks like this

```
~/
  .vimrc
  .vim
     autoload
       pathogen.vim
     bundle
       nerdtree
  .viminfo
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Looks like you copied the `pathogen.vim` directly from the browser, which has all the HTML tags in it.

Try running following command and try again -

```
curl -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://tpo.pe/pathogen.vim
```

More on [pathogen installation](https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen#installation).

Comment: Thank you this worked, although I am confused why it pulled the HTML tags?

Comment: Depends on how you copied the file. Most likely you did select all from a page where the file was shown with some syntax highlighting etc in browser.

Comment: This worked for me when an update script borked my pathogen installation.  Reinstall!

Comment: check if you are behind proxy when executing the curl. If you could not download it, just copy manually and paste it in autoload directory

Comment: That didn't help :(

Answer (score 2):

The answer already posted (and accepted) is probably correct for the issue as it originally stood.

Today I had the same issue, but the accepted answer did not fix it.  Upon investigation, it seems the resource has moved (possibly temporarily) and is now sat behind an invalid SSL certificate.

This worked for me:

```
curl --insecure -LSso ~/.vim/autoload/pathogen.vim https://raw.githubusercontent.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/master/autoload/pathogen.vim
```

Comment: Thank you for this - It seemed for a while only Unix people were allowed to use pathogen!

Comment: For some reason that didn't work for me...

Comment: @Liker777 Did it throw an error or anything?

Comment: @wally for now I just got rid of that because I was tired to resolve plugs of pathogen. I merely install plugins manually for now and it is much easier...

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem "Ubuntu 16.04"

And this solution:
https://github.com/tpope/vim-pathogen/issues/50

.vimrc:

`set nocp
" set rtp+=/path/to/rtp/that/included/pathogen/vim " if needed
call pathogen#infect()
syntax on
filetype plugin indent on`